# Selenium find_element try except ''WebElement' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

I am searching on a webpage for the ID `lieferschein`.

If I am searching without a try and except block, its possible for me to find the ID,

```
tab_check = driver.find_element_by_id('lieferschein')
```

if not

```
try:
    tab_check = driver.find_element_by_id('lieferschein')
    # break
except:
    pass
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

Whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pickle

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

abURL = 'https://farm01.afterbuy.de/afterbuy/auktionsliste.aspx?AWebayname=&AWFilter=37&AWSuchwort=&AWRENummer=&AWFilter2=0&awmaxart=500&maxgesamt=1000&AWEmail=&AWDatumVon=&AWDatumBis=&AWBezug=EndeDerAuktion&AWPLZ=&AWBetrag=&AWBetragBezug=1&AWStammID=&AWLaenderkennung=&AWLaenderkennungBezug=rechnung&AWLabelDynSearchField1=ShippingAddress&AWDynSearchField1=&AWLabelDynSearchField2=AlterItemNumber1&AWDynSearchField2=&AWDynamicSorting=0&AWLabelDynSearchField3=AlterItemNumber&AWDynSearchField3=&searchUserTag1=0&searchUserTag2=0&searchUserTag3=0&searchUserTag4=0&killordersession=0&art=SetAuswahl'

download_dir = "C:\\Users\\Oli\\Documents"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(abURL)

cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

for tab in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to.window(tab)
    try:
        tab_check = driver.find_element_by_id('lieferschein')
        # break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

i have added at the end the 'NoSuchElementException', now i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Oli\PycharmProjects\excel_example\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\Oli\PycharmProjects\excel_example\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Oli\PycharmProjects\excel_example\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Oli\PycharmProjects\excel_example\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"lieferschein"}
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable
```

Comment: Could you show us the whole code?

Comment: Update the question with some more of your code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `except: pass`, this catches every possible exception, some exceptions that occurred are ignored for time being but will silently make a problem later which will be harder to debug.

`NoSuchElementException` exception is raised by `.find_element_by_id('anyID')`, so its better to explicitly mention it for `except`.

```
try:
    tab_check = driver.find_element_by_id('lieferschein')
    # break
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('No element of that id present!')
```

Comment: Well thank you, i allready added this NoSuchElementException, but i think i changed while i added this exception the code so i got another error... Thank you pretty much!